# Is export {default} from './Component' valid ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I ask this because, If I do this in index.js

```
import Comp from './Component';

export default Comp
```

Then doing `import Component from 'src/Component'` WebStorm would not report as error,

but if I do in index.js

```
export { default } from './Component';
```

Then doing `import Component from 'src/Component'` WebStorm will say `Component` is not found. As far as I know it's valid and the code actually works, but is it part of the standard of ES6 this style of exporting?

Comment: What about `export * from './Component'`;

Comment: Yes, it's valid ES6. If WebStorm doesn't recognise it, it appears to be their fault.

Comment: Yeah exactly what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do a named export:

```
export { default as Component } from './Component';
```

then you would need to import it like that:

```
import { Component } from './path';
```

Comment: wouldn't that be a named export? so the `import would be import { Component } from 'src/Component'`

Comment: indeed. that is a named export.

Comment: there is a [proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from) of what you are seeking for

Comment: The proposal is for `export default from`, but `export { default } from` is fine in ES6.